# Cannot flush updates when React is already rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert

I'm trying to show an alert when the API returns an error. For the alert window I'm using sweetalert2. In my render method I'm checking if the error message contains content. If it contains an error message I want to show the user an alert.

When I submit the form, I make an API call. If it returns an error the reducer changes the store (state) and it renders the page again.

Since I added the line below, I keep getting an error:

```
{saveLabelFetchError && this.toggleAlertFailure(saveLabelFetchError)}
```

error:

> index.js:1375 Warning: unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates 
>    when React is already rendering.

My component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

import { saveLabelValueRequest } from "../../actions/labels";

import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import "./styles.css";
import Button from "@kof/button";

export class NewLabels extends Component {
  state = {
    labelInput: ""
  };

  inputChangedhandler = e => {
    this.setState({ labelInput: e.target.value });
  };

  toggleAlertFailure = message => {
    Swal.fire({
      type: "error",
      title: "Oops...",
      text: message
    });
  };

  saveLabel = event => {
    event.persist();
    event.preventDefault();
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
      cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, save it."
    }).then(result => {
      if (result.value) {
        const labelKeyUuid = this.props.labelKey.uuid;
        const labels = event.target.elements.labels.value;
        this.props.saveLabelValue(labelKeyUuid, labels);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { load, saveLabelFetchError } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.saveLabel}>
          <textarea onChange={this.inputChangedhandler}></textarea>
          <textarea></textarea>
          <Button onClick={() => load(this.state.labelInput)}>Preview</Button>
          <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
        </form>
        {saveLabelFetchError && this.toggleAlertFailure(saveLabelFetchError)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

NewLabels.propTypes = {
  saveLabelFetchError: PropTypes.string,
  isFetching: PropTypes.bool,
  labelKey: PropTypes.object,
  saveLabelValue: PropTypes.func
};

NewLabels.defaultProps = {
  saveLabelFetchError: "",
  labelKey: {},
  isFetching: false,
  saveLabelValue: () => {}
};

export default connect(
  state => ({
    saveLabelFetchError: state.labelsStore.saveLabelError,
    isFetching: state.labelsStore.isFetching,
    labelKey: state.labelsStore.labelKey
  }),
  dispatch =>
    bindActionCreators(
      {
        saveLabelValue: saveLabelValueRequest
      },
      dispatch
    )
)(NewLabels);
```

I would like to know why i keep getting this error message in my console.

Comment: Same issue.  The code I am getting it on has not been changed.  Wondering if this is due to a React update.

Comment: I started getting this as well right after updating react.  Also using Sweet Alert, so I think it's something somewhere in sweet alert.

Comment: It's related to the sweet package.

Answer (score 22):

```js
{saveLabelFetchError && this.toggleAlertFailure(saveLabelFetchError)}
```

You are trying to update the dom before render cycle i.e before component has mounted. hence, you are getting an error.

Ideally, you should avoid using any library that mutates dom directly (not via `react` APIs) with react lib. You can read more from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html)

The solution is to check if there is a change in props value, if so then show error popup. And also make sure we are not mutating dom during react's render cycle.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

import { saveLabelValueRequest } from "../../actions/labels";

import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import "./styles.css";
import Button from "@kof/button";

export class NewLabels extends Component {
  state = {
    labelInput: "",
    prevSaveLabelFetchError: ""
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (props.saveLabelFetchError !== state.prevSaveLabelFetchError) {
      this.toggleAlertFailure(props.saveLabelFetchError);
      return {
        prevSaveLabelFetchError: props.saveLabelFetchError
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  inputChangedhandler = e => {
    this.setState({ labelInput: e.target.value });
  };

  toggleAlertFailure = message => {
    Swal.fire({
      type: "error",
      title: "Oops...",
      text: message
    });
  };

  saveLabel = event => {
    event.persist();
    event.preventDefault();
    Swal.fire({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
      cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, save it."
    }).then(result => {
      if (result.value) {
        const labelKeyUuid = this.props.labelKey.uuid;
        const labels = event.target.elements.labels.value;
        this.props.saveLabelValue(labelKeyUuid, labels);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { load } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.saveLabel}>
          <textarea onChange={this.inputChangedhandler}></textarea>
          <textarea></textarea>
          <Button onClick={() => load(this.state.labelInput)}>Preview</Button>
          <Button type="submit">Save</Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

NewLabels.propTypes = {
  saveLabelFetchError: PropTypes.string,
  isFetching: PropTypes.bool,
  labelKey: PropTypes.object,
  saveLabelValue: PropTypes.func
};

NewLabels.defaultProps = {
  saveLabelFetchError: "",
  labelKey: {},
  isFetching: false,
  saveLabelValue: () => {}
};

export default connect(
  state => ({
    saveLabelFetchError: state.labelsStore.saveLabelError,
    isFetching: state.labelsStore.isFetching,
    labelKey: state.labelsStore.labelKey
  }),
  dispatch =>
    bindActionCreators(
      {
        saveLabelValue: saveLabelValueRequest
      },
      dispatch
    )
)(NewLabels);
```

You can also look at [react wrapper for sweetalert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2-react-content)

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue when 2 actions were internally calling the same action type in redux. Check that no 2 actions are calling the same action type simultaneously

Answer (score -3):

Try this code snippet:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(true)

const renderFunc = () => {
    ...
    setState(false)
}

state && renderFunc()
```